# Запись аудио из js

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

Как можно создать любой звуковой файл средствами js с кнопками запись и стоп.

Recordjs не предлагайте,  т.к. он поддерживается только хромом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как вариант JSSoundRecorder

Их [демо](https://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/)

[Github](https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder)

Вот поддержка в браузерах [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext),
кроме IE и Opera mini

И нужен https, без него браузер не разрешит использовать микрофон